# cant access realtime database of firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I had initialized the Firebase in my project through downloading the `google-services.JSON` file after initializing the realtime database. `console.log(database.ref)` returns the correct link for the database but for some reason I am not able to read to write data into the database

one thing I noticed is that

```
try {
  await database().ref('users/123').set({
    name: '5',
    age: 31,
  });
  console.log('done?');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', error);
} finally {
  console.log('error?');
}
```

the finally block is not getting executed for some reason..

In terms of reading the database it was working fine at some point but now that do doesn't seem to execute. This happened when I tried to fix the write issue by adding the

`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')`

and dependencies in the build.gradle file inside app folder of android. I tried rolling back the changes but still no luck.

Don't know how I was able to read before this and its really frustrating

update:
Here the snapshot is updated and its not reflected in the database when I check the firebase console

```
database().ref('users').set('uid');
database()
.ref('users')
.on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
                });
```

and when I put an await before the set

```
await database().ref('users').set('uid');
```

it seems to be stuck on that line and the rest of the code is not executed. I'm not shown any errors.

Also i am not able to read data from database too for some reason

Could some explain whats happening and what I could do about it?

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What "service.json" file? Are you referring to a service account? That should NOT be used for the client SDK. Also can you share complete code so we can see where `database()` is coming from?

Comment: @Dharmaraj The React Native Firebase bindings use `database()` as a top-level function. See https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#usage. I'm also guessing that OP means `google-services.json`, which is the correct file for Android apps.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for clarifying! I thought of the JS SDK 

Comment: sorry about the, by services I meany ```google-services.json``` file

Comment: Check everything from top to bottom: Have you checked your user rights, API key, etc. are OK in your Google Cloud Console? Does your app actually connect to the firebase?

Comment: @Chistian Bonato Could you tell how can I check if my app connects to firebase? I think the API keys are all right as I downloaded straight from the firebase and the rules are all set to true. And I cant seem to capture any http requests in the debugger